# Homogenous equation with only one solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a 2x3 homogenous equation with only one solution?

I've tried looking for one but I am almost convinced that there is no such.

Comment: If (that's a big if in your question) a homogenous equation has only one solution, what solution would that be?

Comment: Yes, I am a curious if such solution exists

Comment: No, because when you row reduce to solve the system you'll have a free variable.

Comment: What is according to you a homogenous equation? If it is a matrix equation for example, then it is possible. Three linear equation with 2 variables or 2 linear equations with 3 variables that all have zero on the right side of the "=" sign, is a homogenous system and the trivial solution works.

Comment: A homogeneous equation always has the trivial solution. I believe he's asking if there are any systems with 2 equations in 3 unknowns that have only the trivial solution. I don't think there are any.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is $Ax = 0$, denote

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} A_1 & A_2 \end{array}\right], \quad x = \left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ \hline x_2 \end{array}\right].$$

where $A_1$ is of order $2 \times 2$, $A_2$ is of order $2 \times 1$, and $x$ is split accordingly. Now,

$$Ax = A_1x_1 + A_2x_2.$$

If you set $x_2 = 0$, then

$$Ax = A_1x_1 = 0$$

is a homogenous system, with $0$, $1$, or infinitely many solutions, depending on $A_1$. However, if you set $x_2 = 1$, you get

$$A_1x_1 + A_2 = 0,\tag{*}$$

i.e.,

$$A_1x_1 = -A_2,$$

which is a nonhomogenous system which, again, can have $0$, $1$, or infinitely many solutions, depending on the same $A_1$. In other words, this system has the same number of solutions as the system $(*)$. All together, for $x$, we have $0$, $2$, or infinitely many solutions, depending on $A_1$.

We can do so for any value of $x_2$, obtaining either no solutions or inifinitely many of them.